# How to find the service pack level in ArcGIS Addin?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, add-in

I can query the current version from [RuntimeInfo.Version](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Version_Property/00460000002m000000/). But I would also like to know what service pack is also installed. Do I need to just check the registery key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESRI\ArcGIS\RealVersion. Or is there a proper ArcObject that allows such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a better way then trying to read the registry key.

This [page](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30104) can be used as a lookup from version number to service pack.

```c#
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
```

Comment: +1 I guess we can safely assume build numbers always increase, so you can just compare to see if the build number you require against whatever the build number is in the FileVersion.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall That seems to be the case. The only thing I'm worried about is that the service packs don't update the executable version. I don't have any evidence that can happen, but I know that some DLLs don't always match...